# Remove trailing commas from header and footer with sed

Tags: csv, unix, sed

I would like to remove commas from the header and footer of my file. I'm using the following command, which removes the commas, but it scans through all lines in the file, which I don't want to.

```
cat DBS_xx_2014-09-23_234.csv | sed 's/[,\t]*$//' > output.csv
```

Input file:

```
000N5          DBS   103151201409220007770001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX  
101RN5      DBS      103151201409220007770001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Expected output:

```
000N5          DBS   103151201409220007770001
10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX  
101RN5      DBS      103151201409220007770001
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: 000N5          DBS   103151201409220007770001                         10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX                      101RN5      DBS      103151201409220007770001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sed command will remove all the commas only from the first and last line.

```
$ sed '1s/,\+//g;$s/,\+//g' file
000N5          DBS   103151201409220007770001 
10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX  
101RN5      DBS      103151201409220007770001
```

Comment: same error input file is binary  and I think the reason why because number of rows in the data data keep the 'NUL' at the end if the POSTCODE length is 7. For Example  ,,,,,,BA2 7RH   hope made sense Thanks again for your help.  I've also check by removing those rows keep the 'NU'L at the end of rows and its works sed 's/[,\t ]*$//' DBS_cc_2014-09-25_12345.csv > xx.csv

Comment: Any tip to remove 'NUL' at the end of the row... ? Thanks again for your help.